# how can calculate of terminal velocity in water tank?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity

I want to calculate the final velocity of a steel sphere of $10 \text{mm}$ diameter, falling inside a $1\text{m}$ height tank.
Also, how to calculate the drag force and the buoyancy force?

Answer (score 1):

For the drag force you can use the Stokes drag
$$F=6\pi\eta r$$ where $\eta$ is the dynamic viscosity of the fluid and $r$ the radius of the ball.

The buoyancy force is according to Archimedean‘s principle given by 
$$F=\rho g V$$ where $\rho$ is the fluid‘s density and $V$ the volume of the displaced fluid (that is in your case the ball‘s volume).

If you now put all forces together you will get the equation of motion.